# Convert JSON to an Typescript array?

Tags: json, angular

I have a JSON file

```
{
    "competitions": [
        { "name": "1.HNL"},
        { "name": "2.HNL"}
    ]
}
```

... and an interface

```
interface ICompetition {
    "name": string
  }
```

In my Angular component I am trying to load this JSON to an array like this:

```
competitions: ICompetition[] = Array.of(competitionJson.competitions);
```

but I get this error:

```
Type '{ name: string; }[][]' is not assignable to type 'ICompetition[]'.
  Property '"name"' is missing in type '{ name: string; }[]' but required in type 'ICompetition'.
```

I have added "resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true in compilerOptions in tsconfig.json

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `competitions: ICompetition[] = competitionJson.competitions`? With no `Array.of`?

Comment: You are right, thanks!